# How to show that $f(x) = \frac{x}{sinh(x)}$ is analytic at $x = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find that if the ordinary differential equation 
$$y^{'} - \frac{y}{\sinh(x)} = 0$$ has a regular singular point at $\ x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This equation is quite simple to solve
$$y^{'} - \frac{y}{\sinh(x)} = 0 \implies \frac {y'}y=\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}$$ Integrating
$$\log(y)=\int \frac{dx}{\sinh(x)}$$ Now, using the equivalent of the tangent half-angle subsitution that is to say $$t=\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\implies x=2 \tanh ^{-1}(t)\implies dx=\frac{2dt}{1-t^2}$$ and $\sinh(x)=\frac{2 t}{1-t^2}$
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sinh(x)}=\int \frac{1-t^2}{2 t}\frac{2dt}{1-t^2} =\int \frac{dt}t=\log(t)+C=\log \left(\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+C$$ Exponentiating
$$y=C \tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$